# multiplying letter of string by digits of number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to multiply letter of string by digits of number. For example for a word "number" and number "123"
output would be "nuummmbeerrr". How do I create a function that does this? My code is not usefull, because it doesn't work.

I have only this

```
def new_word(s):
    b=""
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if i % 2 == 0:
            b = b + s[i] * int(s[i+1])    

return b
```

for new_word('a3n5z1') output is *aaannnnnz* .

Comment: *My code is not usefull* - don't be afraid to post that code here, it's important to show your current efforts

Comment: is the number an int or a string? (`123` or `"123"`?)

Comment: The number 123 is int.

Comment: *"My code is not usefull, because it doesn't work."* You might be closer to the solution than you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will solve your issue, feel free to modify it to fit your needs.

```
from itertools import cycle

numbers = cycle("123")
word = "number"

output = []

for letter in word:
  output += [letter for _ in range(int(next(numbers)))]

string_output = ''.join(output)
```

**EDIT:**

Since you're a beginner This will be easier to understand for you, even though I suggest reading up on the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) module since its the right tool for this kind of stuff.

```
number = "123"
word = "number"


output = []
i = 0

for letter in word:
  if(i == len(number)):
    i = 0
  output += [letter for _ in range(int(number[i]))]
  i += 1

string_output = ''.join(output)
print(string_output)
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont know "cycle". Is there otherr solution for beginners?

Comment: I would say this is a much easier to understand form than the top scoring answer.

Answer (score 3):

Using list comprehension and without `itertools`:

```py
number = 123
word = "number"

new_word = "".join([character*n for (n, character) in zip(([int(c) for c in str(number)]*len(str(number)))[0:len(word)], word)])

print(new_word)

# > 'nuummmbeerrr'
```

What it does (with more details) is the following:

```py
number = 123
word = "number"

# the first trick is to link each character in the word to the number that we want
# for this, we multiply the number as a string and split it so that we get a list...
# ... with length equal to the length of the word
numbers_to_characters = ([int(c) for c in str(number)]*len(str(number)))[0:len(word)]

print(numbers_to_characters)

# > [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

# then, we initialize an empty list to contain the repeated characters of the new word
repeated_characters_as_list = []

# we loop over each number in numbers_to_letters and each character in the word
for (n, character) in zip(numbers_to_characters, word):
    repeated_characters_as_list.append(character*n)

print(repeated_characters_as_list)

# > ['n', 'uu', 'mmm', 'b', 'ee', 'rrr']

new_word = "".join(repeated_characters_as_list)

print(new_word)

# > 'nuummmbeerrr'
```

Comment: Given how new the user is and doesnt know utils like cycle it might be easier to write this for them in a verbose for loop rather than long list comprehension

Comment: You're right - I edited my answer with an explained verbose version of the one-liner!

Comment: nice. instead of `"".join([character]*n)` you can just use `character*n`

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that we could do that

Comment: I would still say this is a very complicated solution for a beginner.  Using list comprehension, slicing, zip, and join all in a single answer is probably a little overkill for a person who is a beginner. You should at least be more verbose with `([int(c) for c in str(number)]*len(str(number)))[0:len(word)]`. You will actually get a cleaner answer if you don't use list comp (like yxor's answer).

Answer (score 1):

you can use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to match each digit to its respective char in the word (using [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) for the case the word is longer), then just multiply the char by that digit, and finally join to a single string.

try this:

```py
from itertools import cycle

word = "number"
number = 123

number_digits = [int(d) for d in str(number)]

result = "".join(letter*num for letter,num in zip(word,cycle(number_digits)))
print(result)
```

Output:

```
nuummmbeerrr
```

Comment: Thanks, I dont know "cycle". Is there otherr solution for beginners?

Comment: @piteer I linked to the official docs, if you'll want to learn :) other answers proposed solutions without it.